# SwiftUI: ForEach filters boolean

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I'm trying desperately with ForEach to only display what has the value true. No matter what I try, false is also displayed. The air is out now and I think it's so simple that I just don't see it. Here is a piece of code to which it should apply:

```
import SwiftUI

struct txt: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var show: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var array = [
        txt(id: 000, text: "True", show: true),
        txt(id: 001, text: "True", show: true),
        txt(id: 002, text: "True", show: true),
        txt(id: 003, text: "False", show: false),
        ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(array.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                   Text("\(self.array[idx].text)")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `ForEach` like this:

```swift
ForEach(array) { arr in
     if arr.show {
         Text("\(arr.text)")
     }
}
```

Comment: Arrgh! That is what I was looking for. My mistake was stupid. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
List(array.filter { $0.show }){ (item) in
    Text(item.text)
}
```

UPDATE:

```
let ids = [0,2]
let filteredItems = array.filter { ids.contains($0.id)}
```

gives you filtered collection with **two items only** where Element.id == 0 or Element.id == 2

array.filter { $0.show } is **collection of three items**, where Element.show == true

you can use it as source of data

```
List(array.filter { ids.contains($0.id) }){ (item) in
    Text(item.text)
}
```

and it will produce one Text for each of its source collection

both conditions (or more) could be applied with any logical operators, as you want

Comment: Thank you. Is there a possibility in the solution to additionally limit the ForEach? For example, just output id: 000 and id: 001, omit 002 completely and then 003 again?

Comment: Quasi limit the range additionally. The filtering however leave as it is.