# ForEach on sorted dictionary: Xcode hangs on building with if block

Tags: xcode, macos, if-statement, foreach, swiftui

I have a simple dictionary such as follows:

```swift
let testDict = [
    "a": "apple",
    "b": "banana",
    "c": "cherry"
]
```

To render it in a view, using an answer from [SwiftUI iterating through dictionary with ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675532/swiftui-iterating-through-dictionary-with-foreach#answer-59244354), I use:

```swift
ForEach(testDict.sorted(by: >), id: \.key) { key, value in
   Text(value)
}
```

and it works well enough. I would now like to filter the list with an `if` block as per [SwiftUI: ForEach filters boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60138431/swiftui-foreach-filters-boolean#answer-60138481) .However, if I attempt to include an `if` block:

```swift
ForEach(testDict.sorted(by: >), id: \.key) { key, value in
   if key != "b" {
       Text(value)
   }
}
```

XCode seems to hang (it just takes a very long time) and eventually gives up with these messages:

> Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

at the very end of the ContentView struct. This is not very helpful, and I can’t see why it takes XCode so long to give up.

How do I include an `if` block in a `ForEach` ?

I real life, the dictionary comes from a CoreData model, but the above sample gives the same problems.

I am developing on XCode 12.1, targeting MacOS 10.15

**Update**

I have since had success with the following:

```swift
ForEach(testDict.filter({$0.key != "b"}).sorted(by: >), id: \.key) { key, value in
   Text(value)
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and it worked perfectly fine for me. I'm using Xcode `Version 12.2 beta 3`. Does this simple example you gave work on its own?

Comment: @George_E I’ve dropped the sample into a Playground, and it immediately gives me the error `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need view in ForEach content, so use Group, like

```
ForEach(testDict.sorted(by: >), id: \.key) { key, value in
   Group {
     if key != "b" {
       Text(value)
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for coming to the rescue. This explains why `if` works in some examples and not others.